# Redirecting from a domain to a specific url of a Django project

Tags: django, apache, .htaccess

I own two domains example1.com and example2.com. I setup example1.com to point to the the "/" of my Django project, meaning that example1.com/* is handled by urls.py. I want example2.com to actually point to a specific Django URL (e.g. "/123"), which is currently accessed at example1.com/123.

Ideally, when you go to example2.com/abc, Django would treat the request as if it came from example1.com/123/abc, but the URL would still be "example2.com/abc".

Here's what I have currently in my .htaccess file, but example2.com leads to "Server not found" in Firefox.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^\.com(.*)$ http://example1.com/123/$1 [L]
```

This is my first experience doing something like with the htaccess file, so apologies if something is off.  I am using mod_wsgi (on WebFaction)--does this still support rewriting URLs?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your htaccess file in the root directory of your `example2.com` site.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example2\.com$ [NC]
#proxy all requests to example1.com/123
RewriteRule (.*) http://example1.com/123/$1 [P]
```

Comment: That didn't seem to do it, I'm getting the same error.  Note that example1.com has the same root directory.  Is that a problem?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @gwintrob if you try to access `http://example1.com/123/abc` directly in the browser, does that work?

Comment: Hi Ulrich.  Yes, I can access that link directly, but I'm trying to access it by going to example2.com/abc.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to edit httpd.conf, as opposed to .htaccess.  Here are the relevant lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)?example2.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example1.com/123/$1 [P,L]
```

These lines go directly beneath the `WSGIScriptAlias` that directs to the Django project .wsgi file.  I don't know why the .htaccess file did not do the trick, but hopefully this helps out others with the same problem.

Thanks!